# JsonPath - cache the JSON and then perform multiple queries?

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have inherited some code that does a lot of JsonPath queries against a single JSON file. For each query it passes in the JSON file and the query. This then becomes a call to JsonPath.read(jsonFile, jpathQuery).

Is there a way to avoid having it build up whatever internal structure it needs of the JSON to then perform the query? Is there a way to have it build up the internal model of the JSON once and then perform multiple queries against it?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [this jsonpath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

In their docs they have this

> The simplest most straight forward way to use JsonPath is via the
>   static read API.
>
> ```
> String json = "...";
> List<String> authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
> ```
>
> If you only want to read once this is OK. In case you need to read an
>   other path as well this is not the way to go since the document will
>   be parsed every time you call JsonPath.read(...). To avoid the problem
>   you can parse the json first.
>
> ```
> String json = "..."; Object document =
> Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json);
> String author0 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.store.book[0].author");
> String author1 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.store.book[1].author");
> ```